# Why are these conductors equal?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I found in literature at least 3 definitions for "conductor of an
extension".$\def\fm{{\frak m}}\def\ff{{\frak f}}\let\ss\subset
\def\cA{{\cal A}}\let\a\alpha\let\z\zeta\def\cE{{\cal E}}\let\imp\Longrightarrow\def\Q{{\Bbb Q}}$

From Ideal point of view, (cf. Bochéat-Mischler or Janusz or Wikipedia) the conductor
is the gcd of the modules $\fm$ such that $P_\fm\ss\ker\cA$ ($\cA$ the
Artin map and $P_\fm$ the fractional, principal ideals with a generator
$\a,\:\a=1\mod\fm$). In pedantic language: "the Artin map factors
through the ray-class group"

From idelic point of view (Lang or Neukirsch) it is the smallest module such
that $\cE_\fm\ss N(\cE_K)$ where $\cE_K$ is the inversible idèle of the
extension $K$,
$N=N_{K/F}$ the idelic norm and $\cE_\fm$ the inversible idèle $=1\mod\fm$.

Nancy Childress gives another one: The smallest $\fm$ such that $\cE_\fm\ss
F^*N(J_K)=\ker \cA$ (with $\cA$ the idelic Artin map).

As $\cE_K\ss J_K$ the Childress-conductor divides Lang-conductor : $\ff_C|\ff_L$

One can prove (not obvious at all!) the $L$-conductor verify ideal point of view $\cE_\fm\ss N(\cE_K)\imp P_\fm\in \ker\cA$ an consequently
Ideal-conductor divides Lang-conductor $\ff_I|\ff_L$

I have no idea about other divisibility, but I think it's essential to prove that all these concepts are actually the same one.

Generally, books given as exercise a proof that the old character conductor (least $m$ / $K\ss\Q[\z_m]$ coincide with the more complicate one. But I didn't find any proof that the conductor notions from different authors are in fact the same one.

Has someone an idea, a reference?